# TinyMCE - Does not appear some menu buttons

Tags: jquery, button, tinymce

Hi new with TinyMCE Plugin and when I set up in my php page, the interface looks like :

[image]

This is the simple code I added:

```
<script src="../tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector:'textarea',
        height: 200,
        width: 500
    });
</script>
```

Regarding to the TinyMCE web page, it should looks like this:

[image]

What do you think could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your configuration this option:

```
menubar: "tools table format view insert edit"
```

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:menu

Comment: TinyMce got tons of onpions, Here you have full config example:
http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php

Comment: I did it, with no results. Also, I added more `width` just by the way.

Comment: Give me a minute will try to create a config for you.

Comment: Dude, in that **Full Example** I found `plugins` attribute that makes me the day. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Good luck with this:)